# How to parametrize a \draw command in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using the following command to draw a 'X' at a particular coordinate (x):

```
\draw [blue, line width=1mm]
      (x)-- ++(-4.5pt,-4.5pt) -- ++(9.0pt,9.0pt)
      ++(-9.0pt,0) -- ++(9.0pt,-9.0pt);
```

However, I don't really like pasting the same code at multiple places where I need the X - so, I'm looking for a way to kind of declare a subroutine which would do this, and take the coordinate as a parameter. (I tried using `\tikzset`, apparently that works with nodes - I wasn't able to get a decent example using `\draw`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about just this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\myX}[2][]{
\draw[#1] [blue, line width=1mm]
      (#2)-- ++(-4.5pt,-4.5pt) -- ++(9.0pt,9.0pt)
      ++(-9.0pt,0) -- ++(9.0pt,-9.0pt);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\myX[dashed]{0,0}
\myX[dotted]{2,-1}
\myX{3,4}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, I was hoping for a method similar to how I can pass parameters to a tikz style, which can be used by nodes, while still having the flexibility of adding further options to a few of the \node commands  -having to use a newcommand essentially does not allow me  the flexibility of adding on separate parameters (like, say, a dashed X!)...

Comment: @TCSGrad See my last edit.